# Call Fortran from Python on spyder, windows 10, "AttributeError: module 'myflib' has no attribute 'function'"

Tags: python, windows, fortran, attributeerror, f2py

I'm currently trying to call a function contained in Fortran code from a Python script.
To do this, I've tried the example available on https://www.matecdev.com/posts/fortran-in-python.html.

I've created "my_fortran_lib.f90" which contains the function defined as

```
!
! my_fortran_lib.f90:
!
function foo(a) result(b)
    implicit none
   
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: a(:,:)
    complex(kind=8) :: b(size(a,1),size(a,2))
   
    b = exp((0,1)*a)
   
end function foo
```

Then I executed the following command `f2py3 -c -m myflib2 my_fortran_lib.f90` on the command prompt (I use windows 10)
I have 2 outputs "myflib2.cp311-win_amd64.pyd" and "libmy_fortr.VGRWKJX2MMMS3CK3OCJQHKECLLH3CKTE.gfortran-win_amd64.dll" contained in the folder "myflib2" (which is in the same folder as my others libraries)

However, when I run my code on spyder,

```
import myflib2
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]], order='F')
myflib2.foo(a)
```

I have the following results:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zawL0.png)

```
myflib2.foo(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[10], line 1
    myflib2.foo(a)

AttributeError: module 'myflib2' has no attribute 'foo'
```

it can find the folder myflib2 but can't run the function that is supposed to be in the Fortran code.

would you have any idea of the source of my problem?

thanks in advance,

I have tried to use

- other format of Fortran as f90, f
- other function

but it does not work

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [mcve]. It is very important to include all error messages and similar output as text into the question itself. Do not use pictures for this content. It is very important that the error messages are searchable.

Comment: Where does your Python installation come from?

Comment: Does moving the dll file to the same level of the python script work?

Comment: It does not work @SyndRain

Comment: I use python 3.11.5 which was dowload on https://www.python.org/downloads/,
here is its path « C:\Users\Eva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\ ».
@VladimirFГероямслава